# Can I use BIND in place of DNSCrypt?

Tags: dns, dnssec

I was using [DNSCrypt](https://github.com/simonclausen/dnscrypt-autoinstall) on my personal computer (linux). I uninstalled it, and now I'm getting errors reinstalling. I believe development on DNSCrypt was being abandoned anyway, because Cisco/OpenDNS bought it.

I was looking into [BIND](https://www.isc.org/downloads/bind/) as a replacement for that, to choose my DNS and utilize DNSSEC. I want to be able to use DNSSEC providers (https://dnscrypt.info/public-servers/).

Am I wrong to think I can use this on my personal computer?

Comment: For a recursive caching nameserver, have a look at `unbound` instead of `bind`. It comes with everything needed for DNSSEC. Look at `dnssec-trigger` too (based on unbound) for hostile environments/ISP/DNS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was using DNSCrypt on my personal computer (linux). I uninstalled it, and now I'm getting errors reinstalling. I believe development on DNSCrypt was being abandoned anyway, because Cisco/OpenDNS bought it.

DNSCrypt is a protocol not a software. It has multiple implementations. The specific implementation you refer to is [dnscrypt-proxy](https://github.com/jedisct1/dnscrypt-proxy/) which was last updated 2 days ago. DNSCrypt is not related to OpenDNS.

> I was looking into BIND as a replacement for that, to choose my DNS and utilize DNSSEC

Bind is not a replacement for DNSCrypt. DNSSec does not encrypt DNS but only adds signatures to provide an authenticated response. Signing in DNSSec is done by the owners of the domain (i.e. the authority) whereas with DNSCurve the signing is done by the DNSCurve server (which is not the authority for the domain).

> I want to be able to use DNSSEC providers (https://dnscrypt.info/public-servers/).

There are no such thing as DNSSec providers. DNSSec simply works like normal DNS. Servers for the DNSCrypt protocol can not be used by normal DNS software.

Comment: I didn't realize dnscrypt-proxy was in version 2. Very happy you pointed that out. It looks like they definitely improved development and Linux availability. This is what I was looking for.